# Why Jenkins lost connection with Tomcat server

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins is lost connection with the Tomcat server. I also has added private key in Jenkins credentials.

This is my jenkinsfile for 'Deploy-toTomcat' stage

```
            steps {
              sshagent(['tomcat']) {
                 sh 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/*.war 
                 ubuntu@35.239.69.247:/home/nat/prod/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/webapp.war'
                 }      
             }       
        }
```

This is the error when I am trying to build the pipeline in Jenkins

```
+ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking = no target/WebApp.war ubuntu@35.239.69.247:/home/nat/prod/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/webapps/webapp.war
command-line line 0: missing argument.
lost connection
script returned exit code 1
```

error

```
$ ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 139377 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
```

I also put command ***chmod 777 webapps***
I am following this link *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSMSHGoHVJY&list=PLjNII-Jkdjfz5EXWlGMBRk63PC8uJsHMo&index=7* to deploy the tomcat.

Hope anyone knows can answer my question on how I want to deploy to tomcat. The source code that I test to build the pipeline also from *https://github.com/cehkunal/webapp.git*. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because it did not recognize which one the authorized keys. What I've done

1. delete all previous keys in ./ssh file,
2. ssh-keygen -t rsa
3. mv id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
4. chmod 0600 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
5. chmod 0700 /home/username/.ssh
6. cat id_rsa

Finally insert id_rsa in manage credentials Jenkins.